# Why does my source location change back to original?

Tags: java, netbeans

So guys, every time I change `(refactor->rename)` my source folder for my images, in the `initcomponents` thing it changes back to the old name (old source).

So this is my original source (So my images are in folder `URLToIP`:
[image: original source]

But when I change/refactor then rename my folder to `IPRESOLVER`, it goes back to `URLToIP` after running it one time.

As you can see below, it totally changed the package name to `IPRESOLVER` 
[image]

But a later while in the class code it'll change it back to `URLtoIP`.
[image]

I've already tried changing it manually using notepad++ and it worked. It changes to `IPRESOLVER` as source for images but after one run it gives me an error that the source is once again `URLTOIP`

I changed it here by the way (using Notepad++):
[image]

Since the error is this:
[image]

Which leads me to here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys, I just clicked `build` not the `clean and build` and then voila! It stopped reverting.